# Selenium Chromedriver tests fail from Powershell but pass from Nuget Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium, visual-studio-2013, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run my xunit tests with Selenium from Powershell. However, an odd thing occurs.

From the Nuget Packet manager console, my tests run perfectly with the command:

```
> <xunit_runner_console_path>/xunit.console <xunit_project_path>/MyApp.dll
```

However, my tests timeout when I run that same command from powershell.

When the tests fail, the chrome session does not load my page. After looking at the developer tools I noticed that chrome failed to load files like the following:

```
<link href="<>/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
 <script src="scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Those request failed with 500 server.

What is causing the chromedriver to behave differently?